# How i can write client_id from this Array in cakephp when relation is belongsTo

Tags: arrays, cakephp

I want to give criteria where client_id = $this->user['client_id']; so that loggedIn user can see his own data for his Client.

I dont understand how to get client_id  from below array.

```
[Payment] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [location_id] => 138
                [cashier_id] => 313
                [client_id] => 2
                [pay_date] => 2015-02-13 10:51:54
                [amount_paid] => 28882685
                [total_paid] => 28882685
                [change_due] => 0
                [pay_method] => CA
                [bank] => 
                [ref_no] => 
                [payment_type] => Bill
                [reversal_fee] => 
                [reversal_code] => 
                [reversal] => 1
                [reversal_date] => 
                [reversed_by_id] => 
                [User] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 313
                        [username] => tellerb
                        [client_id] => 8
                    )

                [Location] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 138
                        [name] => Sector 64
                    )

            )
```

Your help will be grateful

Comment: try - $your_array["Payment"]["User"]["client_id"];

Answer (score 0):

Use it as nested associative array

```
$YourArray['Payment']['User']['client_id'];
```

Always check how you reach that field . Here outer Array is Payment , then you goto User then goto client_id.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response